# React selectbox number value is passed as string

Tags: reactjs

I have a controlled select in React with the values `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, '5+', 'unknown'`. When selecting or changing the value I'm getting a string for every value instead of a number for the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

I was searching on Stackoverflow and found a solution where the value is wrapped with `parseInt` but since I also have strings as possible values I'm getting 5 for the '5+' string and NaN for 'unknown'.

Someone a working solution?

**Form component**

```
...    
const { formData, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useForm();

const options = [
    { label: 0, value: 0 },
    { label: 1, value: 1 },
    { label: 2, value: 2 },
    { label: 3, value: 3 },
    { label: 4, value: 4 },
    { label: 5, value: 5 },
    { label: '5+', value: '5+' },
    { label: "I don't know", value: 'unknown' },
];

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
        <select id="numberOfElectricityMeters" name="numberOfElectricityMeters" value={formData.numberOfElectricityMeters} onChange={handleInputChange}>
            <option value=''>Choose an option</option>
            {options.map((option, i) => (
                <option key={i} value={option.value}>
                    {option.label}
                </option>
            ))}
        </select>

        <select id="numberOfGasMeters" name="numberOfGasMeters" value={formData.numberOfGasMeters} onChange={handleInputChange}>
            <option value=''>Choose an option</option>
            {options.map((option, i) => (
                <option key={i} value={option.value}>
                    {option.label}
                </option>
            ))}
        </select>
    </form>
)
```

**useForm**

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
        setFormData((currentValues) => ({ ...currentValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked }));
    } else {
        setFormData((currentValues) => ({ ...currentValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
    }
};
```

Comment: Since the options have both strings and numbers , it is better to treat all values as strings and process them accordingly. If you do want to use `parseInt` then may be renaming `5+` as `FivePlus` would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `isNaN` you can check if the value contains string. (ex: '5+')
if isNan is true, value not parse number.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
   ....
   ....
   var value = !isNaN(e.target.value) && parseInt(e.target.value) ?
               parseInt(e.target.value) : e.target.value;
   setFormData((currentValues) => ({ ...currentValues, [e.target.name]: value }));
   ...
   ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `parseInt()` method, it parses up to the first non-digit and returns whatever it had parsed, so parsing `'5+'` will return you a solid `5`, like you have experienced. To solve this, you can use `Number()` function, because it tries to parse the entire string to a number, and if it is not possible, it returns a `NaN` value.

So, you can implement a custom parser and use it instead of `parseInt`;

```
const customParser = (value) => {

  if(!value) return value;

  const parsedVal = Number(value);
  return (isNaN(parsedVal) ? value : parsedVal);

}
```

Comment: if the value is ''" (empty string), the return value is 0.

Comment: I have edited the code to cover the cases when the input is an empty string, null or undefined.